# Clean approach to store Key-Value "properties"?

Tags: django, django-models

Let say I have one model for cars. Each car has attributes: color, size, weight, etc... I want users to allow the creation of new attributes for each car objects. However I want to share "attributes" so that the attribute "size" only exists once in the db but values exist for each object where users have added them.

My old approach were two models: Car, KeyValue(key: String, value:String) and Car had a 1:m relationship to KeyValue.

Now, to ensure my above constraint I thought of the following:

- Three objects: Car, Key, Value
- Value(Key: Key)
- Car (1:m relation to Value)

However, this reverse approach works very well but does not look "clean" to me. Therefore, I'd like to ask whether a cleaner approach is possbile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i read this
http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/06/11/schemaless-django/

i haven't used this but i think it's ok.

a less complex approach is

django-picklefield
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/

i hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

If your "choices" are malleable, i.e. they can be added to, edited, or deleted from, then the choice should be it's own model. For example:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Car(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, related_name='cars')
```

Comment: I want my users to create their own properties

Answer (score -2):

You should have Cars and CarModels

A CarModel has two list of properties. One that has the "PerModel" attributes for all cars of that models (That means all the cars of that model have the same value), and another one (just the names) of the properties that each car can have a different value "PerCar".

```
CarModel
{
    KeyValue(key: String, value:String) propertyValuesPerModel;
    List(String) propertyNamesPerCar;
}

Car
{
CarModel model;
KeyValue(key: String, value:String) propertiesPerCar; //Keys can only be those that appear on model.propertyNamesPerCar
}
```

Comment: This is very clearly tagged with *Django*, which is a *Python* framework. If you're going to answer, at least do so in the right language.